# Exchange Server 2010 is prompting all Microsoft Outlooks clients for authentication every couple seconds. How do I resolve this?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

My company's Exchange 2K10 started prompting all Outlook Clients for auth Tuesday afternoon. If you just drag the prompt to the side and ignore it email works fine. If you input your username and password it prompts again within 3 seconds to 10 minutes. If you hit cancel or close out of the window, Outlook loses connection to our server. It doesn't prompt immediately on startup. It starts connected. So we have everyone moving the window to the edge of their screen and doing nothing and it continues to work fine for almost all our clients. We have a few people using Outlook Anywhere and they cannot use their email at all.

Domain controllers and Exchange have been rebooted more than once, and all services appear to be functioning. There is nothing in the event/error logs. The network connection is secure, cables, routers and switches are all fully functional.

I know this isn't really a programming question but we're all very stumped.

Comment: This is a wild guess, but... Is the time on the Exchange server(s) correct?

Comment: Yes it is. We ended up just having to hire outside help. I'll report back and answer this question after they figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You might have an outage on your Exchange Web Services (Free/busy, address book) or Public Folders - or possibly even the RPC VirDir. If you're using MAPI, the connection will fail and it will fallback to trying OA (RPC over HTTP) - but if a service is down, that will also fail, but in the meantime, it keeps asking for your creds as it tries to connect.

You should really bookmark this site and use it.
https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/

Also, this is useful powershell:

```
get-exchangeserver | Test-Servicehealth
```

You can see something similar internally by using the "Connection Status" menu item from CTL-right-clicking the Outlook icon in the system tray - but the MAPI failure to either of those services will disappear quickly, you might not catch it. You might see the attempted HTTP connection though.

Comment: No dice. We still have our consultants looking in to the problem. It's been a week and they're starting to run out of ideas.

Comment: What do you see with that site, and Connection Status? Post some config and troubleshooting details if you want more help.

Answer (score 1):

We've had this issue in the past. 
This issue started after the admin password expired/changed and all computers had to have the network (not the outlook) credentials re-entered to have the pop-up disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I want to say we had an issue similar to this one time where it was either our web site monitoring software or anti-virus software.

Was anything done Tuesday or the weekend prior to that Tuesday that could have possibly spurred this issue?

Comment: No. We have our outside help working on it again today. I'll answer this question as soon as they finish and we know what went wrong.